# Delegation of clone() method call in inheritance in java

Tags: java, cloneable

1.Child class extends Parent class.
2.Child class implements Cloneable and overrides clone() method calls super.clone()
3.Parent class doesn't implement Cloneable interface neither it overrides clone() method.

Output:
Both parent and child class state's are cloned.

Question:
How Parent class state is cloned by Object class when Parent class has not implemented marker interface Cloneable?

```
class ParentCloneableClass{
    String val;
    public ParentCloneableClass(String val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
class CloneableClass extends ParentCloneableClass implements Cloneable{
    String name;
    public CloneableClass(String name){
        super("parentClass");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public   CloneableClass clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (CloneableClass) super.clone();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Demo{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        CloneableClass cloneableClass = new CloneableClass("deepak");
        CloneableClass cloneableClassCloned = cloneableClass.clone();
   }
}
```

Comment: `Parent.clone()` delegates to `Object.clone()` *implicitly*

Comment: Parent doesn't override clone(). So, how does parent.clone() invoke object.clone()? If a class doesn't override clone() and if we invoke child.clone() then gets compile time error then how come parent has not override clone() will give a call to parent clone().

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal: Object has the `clone()` method which parent inherits (which all classes inherit). It doesn't need to override anything to have the method.

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal see this example: https://ideone.com/nF4irN. It behaves the same with `clone()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Object` checks the [*runtime* type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) of the object being cloned, not the compile time type. So the object at runtime is of type `Cloneable` which does implements `Cloneable`, hence the `Object` class performs the cloning [accordingly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()):

> The method clone for class `Object` performs a specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface `Cloneable`, then a `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown... Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes ***all its fields*** with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

Comment: Object invocation occurs runtime that's fine, so here the instance of object at runtime is of child, how come object class clone Parent class automatically?

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal It will copy all fields of the child class, including those inherited from parent.